# How to set DIFFERENT image pins in different locations SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, annotations, mapkit, mkannotation

I'm trying to code an app that displays different images on a AppleMap. I managed to set one image pin but I don't know how to set different images.

In my view didLoad I wrote :

```
self.pin = AnnotationPin(title: sport, subtitle: "ouiii", coordinate: coordinate)
                                                            
self.MyMapView.addAnnotation(self.pin)
```

In the viewcontroller I have:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    
    guard !(annotation is MKUserLocation) else {
        return nil
    }

    let annotationIdentifier = "AnnotationIdentifier"

    var annotationView: MKAnnotationView?
    if let dequeuedAnnotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: annotationIdentifier) {
        annotationView = dequeuedAnnotationView
        annotationView?.annotation = annotation
    }
    else {
        annotationView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: annotationIdentifier)
        annotationView?.rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)
    }

    if let annotationView = annotationView {
       
        annotationView.canShowCallout = true
        annotationView.image = UIImage(named: "kite")
    }

    return annotationView
}
```

I made another swift file called annotation which contains:

```
class AnnotationPin:  NSObject, MKAnnotation {
let coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
let title: String?
let subtitle: String?

init(title:String, subtitle: String, coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
    self.title = title
    self.subtitle = subtitle
    self.coordinate = coordinate
    
    super.init()
 }}
```

I already called this class for subtitles and titles and I suppose I can call it again to choose my Image. But I don't know how to do it, and I don't find answers on other topics.

Comment: In `viewForAnnotation` you need to conditionally cast the supplied `annotation` to `AnnotationPin` and then you can access an `image` property that you add to that class.

Comment: I didn't get it... How do I implement that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an `image` property to your `AnnotationPin` class and then in `viewForAnnotation` you use a conditional downcast to see if you are dealing with one of your annotations.  If you are then you can use the `image` property

```
class AnnotationPin:  NSObject, MKAnnotation {
let coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
let title: String?
let subtitle: String?
let image: UIImage?

init(title:String, subtitle: String, image: UIImage, coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
    self.title = title
    self.subtitle = subtitle
    self.coordinate = coordinate
    self.image = image
    super.init()
 }}


func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    
    guard let myAnnotation = annotation as? AnnotationPin  else {
        return nil
    }

    let annotationIdentifier = "AnnotationIdentifier"

    var annotationView: MKAnnotationView?
    if let dequeuedAnnotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: annotationIdentifier) {
        annotationView = dequeuedAnnotationView
        annotationView?.annotation = annotation
    }
    else {
        annotationView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: annotationIdentifier)
        annotationView?.rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)
    }

    if let annotationView = annotationView {
       
        annotationView.canShowCallout = true
        annotationView.image = myAnnotation.image
    }

    return annotationView
}
```

Comment: Thx for your answer. But I still need to know what I should write in the viewdidload?
I tried to add the image property but it says that it can't convert string into UIImage.

Comment: Thxxxxxx!!!!!!!!!!!!
I just added in the view did load : 
self.pin = AnnotationPin(title: sport, subtitle: "ouiii", image: UIImage(named: sport), coordinate: coordinate)

Where sport is my looping variable. It prints everything perfectly!!!

Comment: You can use `UIImage(named:)` to get an image from a string containing its name.